# HTML div element doesn't fall into keyboard tabbing order

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, knockout.js

I have a HTML file in which generating a `<div>` element with knockout css binding.

Now, the problem is the newly/dynamically generated DOM element doesn't fall into the keyboard tabbing order. Keyboard tabbing would skip this DOM and focus on the next DOM.

If I manually set focus using JavaScript focus(), the DOM is accessible (I can navigate through other Divs within this DOM). I've also set the tabindex="0" for this DOM.

But it just doesn't fall under keyboard's logical ordering.
    Any idea what's wrong with the HTML ?

```html
<body class="container">
  <div data-bind="with: toolbarViewModel">
    <div class="toolbar">
      <div class="toolbar-group">
        <button class="toolbar-group-button toggle-button" id="toggle-query-mode" title="Toggle query builder" data-bind="event: { mousedown: onMouseDown, mouseover: onMouseOver, mouseout: onMouseOut, focus: onFocus, blur: onBlur, keydown: onKeyDown, keyup: onKeyUp }">
          <div data-bind="css: { 'toggle-checked': isQueryOpen }">
            <img class="toolbar_icon" src="../../../images/StorageExplorer/ASX_Query_grey_19x.png" data-bind="attr: { src: queryIconSrc }">
          </div>
          <span>Query</span>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="query-panel" tabindex="0" data-bind="css: { 'transition-in': isQueryOpen }">
      <!--ko template: { if: isQueryOpen, name:'queryBuilderTemplate'}-->
      <!--/ko-->
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- End of toolbar -->

  <script type="text/html" id="queryBuilderTemplate">
    <div class="query-builder" data-bind="with: queryViewModel">
      <div class="query-builder-toolbar">
        .....
      </div>
    </div>
  </script>

</body>
```

Comment: post your code?

Comment: Let me know if you need a code

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the relevant code - providing an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) will help us to help you. *"it just doesn't fall under keyboard's logical ordering"* - So is it in the tab order but in the wrong place (e.g., right at the end), or not in the tab order at all?

Comment: So when "isQueryOpen" is true, the 'toggle-checked' CSS gets called which in turns add a new DOM element which is "query-panel". Now the "query-panel" DOM doesn't fall under keyboard navigation order. So It just skip all the Divs under "queryBuilderTemplate" and focus the next DOM which is after "query-panel"(not part of the code.)

Comment: When injecting HTML via knockout without using custom `tabindex` attributes, everything seems to work as expected... Can you provide a reproduction (in the fiddle)? https://jsfiddle.net/97prfp8y/